How can I use select query in the AS clause in DBLINK Query in PostgreSQL?
I am wandering how I can use select query in the AS clause in DBLINK Query in PostgreSQL?
I am connected with remote Database server from my local Database server of PostgreSQL using dblink.
When I am using the query below, it works fine.
SELECT * from dblink
( 'dbname=DBNAME port=xxxx host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx user=***** password=******',
'SELECT * FROM mytable')
AS x(   a int,
b varchar,
c text
);
mytable
| id   | name  |   Description   |
|  1   | John  | he is good      |
|  2   | David | He is excellent |
I have a table tbl_datatype in my database where the data type is stored.
tbl_datatype
|header | d_dype |
| a     | int    |
| b     | varchar|
| c     | text   |
Now I want to use the stored datatype from tbl_datatype in stead of typing manually in AS clause like below:
SELECT * from dblink
( 'dbname=DBNAME port=xxxx host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx user=***** password=******',
'SELECT * FROM mytable')
AS x( select concat(header, ' ', d_type) from tbl_datatype );
Can anyone give me an idea to resolve it?
Thanks in Advance.
expected result
SELECT * from dblink
( 'dbname=DBNAME port=xxxx host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx user=***** password=******',
'SELECT * FROM mytable')
AS x( select concat(header, ' ', d_type) from tbl_datatype );
getting the error 'SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"'
Expected Result:
mytable
| id   | name  |   Description   |
|  1   | John  | he is good      |
|  2   | David | He is excellent |
Can anyone give me an idea to resolve it?
Thanks in Advance.
